# How to edit file from another directory

Tags: php

How to import text from another file to html. i want to have file text.html

where is text:

```html
<h2> some text </h2>
```

and just import to the index code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your question is. Can you revise this to clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PHP file can include plain html files, txt files and of course other PHP files.
Assuming this file is something.php  it can show the content of text.html like this.

```
<?php include('text.html'); ?>
```